# Ограничение положения камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

Вот мой текущий скрипт камеры

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
  {
private Transform target;

void Update()
  {
    target = GameLogic.playerInstantiatePosition.transform;
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -10) + target.position;
  }
}
```

И значение переменной plyerInstantiatePosition

```
playerInstantiatePosition = Instantiate(playerObject, playerSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Но камеры выходит за карту. Как остановить камеру, при приближении к границе?

Comment: нет скриптов под рукой, просто посмотрите как камера работает в стандартном ассете юнити

Comment: Я не вижу, чтобы в вашем коде вообще была определена хоть какая-то граница. Вы просто всегда перемещаете карту за игроком. Вы пытались реализовать какие-то ограничения?

Comment: @M.Green В этом и суть. Мне нужно как-то ограничить камеру.

Comment: вам нужно знать координаты границы. И проверять близка ли камера к ним или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, давайте я сразу объявлю несколько допущений, покажу как реализовать движение с их учётом, а потом вы по аналогии сами подгоните под свой случай.

[У нас была карта-спрайт, ортографическая камера](https://youtu.be/Ga8E9f8MUls), которую я двигал и уверенность в собственных силах. Суть "ограничения" движения заключается в простой логике: у нас есть камера-"экран" определённого разрешения и нам нужно рассчитать на какое расстояние мы можем её сдвигать, чтобы не вылезти за нашу зону, после чего перед тем как двигать камеру мы будем проверять не превышает ли текущий "сдвиг" максимально разрешённый.

```
[SerializeField]
SpriteRenderer _map; //Вы можете использовать, например Box2dCollider для наглядности ограничения.

[SerializeField]
Camera _camera;

Vector2 _xOffset;

Vector2 _yOffset;

Transform _cameraTarget;

//Убедитесь, что GameLogic.playerInstantiatePosition назначается в Awake
void Start()
{   
    _cameraTarget = GameLogic.playerInstantiatePosition.transform; //Запоминаем цель
    CalculateFrustum(); //Считаем "максимальный сдвиг"
}

//Каждый кадр сдвигаемся за игроком
void Update()
{
    ClampedMove(_cameraTarget.position);
}

//"особая" магия передвижения камеры
void ClampedMove(Vector2 newPosition)
{
    float xValue = newPosition.x;
    float yValue = newPosition.y;

    xValue = Mathf.Clamp(xValue, _xOffset.y, _xOffset.x);
    yValue = Mathf.Clamp(yValue, _yOffset.y, _yOffset.x);
    _camera.transform.position = new Vector3(xValue, yValue, _camera.transform.position.z);
}

//Расчет границ для ортографической камеры. Для перспективной камеры система похожа, 
//но нужно считать отсекающую плоскость на дистанции от камеры до карты. Где-то на форуме уже был подробный ответ
void CalculateFrustum()
{
    var rate = (float)Screen.currentResolution.width / Screen.currentResolution.height;
    var bounds = _map.bounds;
    var min = bounds.min;
    var max = bounds.max;

    var size = _camera.orthographicSize;
    _xOffset = new Vector2(max.x - size * rate, min.x + size * rate);
    _yOffset = new Vector2(max.y - size, min.y + size);
}
```

Такой расчёт "ограничения" может выйти боком в редакторе, если в окне Game установлено жесткое ограничение разрешения, а не соотношение сторон. Т.к. считать оно будет исходя из виртуальных размеров окна, а не из реальных (например, установлено 1920:1080, а само окно в редакторе сильно меньше).

Comment: Какой тип у перемененной `_location`? Она используется в методе `CalculateFrustum`, но не объявлялась.

Comment: @Kvantor, а, пардон. переименовал в объявлении и забыл про сам метод) это переменная _map в девичестве. Если вы будете использовать collider, то у него тоже есть .bounds и смысл будет тот же.

Comment: не вышло запустить этот скрипт. Пришлось показать Unity: с какой камерой надо работать (а она у меня одна). Добавил объекту `_camera` атрибут для отображения в инспекторе и повесил на него камеру, на которой, в свою очередь, и висит этот самый скрипт. Теперь всё работает, хотя камера не доходит до правого и левого концов карты, но это не критично.

Comment: @Kvantor, да, логично, что надо было назначить камеру) у меня она просто отдельно бралась. про "не доходит до краёв" - это связано с примечанием после кода, скорее всего) вы его читали?